# Integrate SASS/SCSS with Django

Tags: django, sass

I want to use SASS/SCSS with Django application.

I followed the link https://bitbucket.org/synic/django-sass. 
I installed SASS using sudo pip install sass.

When i run Python manage.py runserver,iam getting error as

**'sass' is not a valid tag library: Template library sass not found, tried django.templatetags.sass**

Can Anyone help me?!

Comment: Did you do step 1 at that link?

Comment: yes, i added 'sass' in installed apps, i installed using sudo pip install sas. When i do syncdb, its fine, but when i run runserver, iam getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

python sass (pip install sass) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sass is different
from django-sass (https://bitbucket.org/synic/django-sass)

Download django sass from https://bitbucket.org/synic/django-sass after that install and setup as documented .

Comment: As you stated, i downloaded the package and installed. But still iam facing that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you first installed sass, the ruby app?

```
$ apt-get install ruby-sass
```

You'll know if it's done properlly; as type `sass` on the command line, does sassy things.

Next, I cloned django-sass (from the other answer):

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:synic/django-sass.git
```

Then navigated to the puled folder and installed it.

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Initially the installation crashed out:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CHANGES.rst'
```

So I quickly created the file:

```
 touch CHANGES.rst
```

and ran the install command again.

no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The django-sass-processor package is a great package that lets you easily integrate SASS/SCSS with Django.

Here's a tutorial on how to set up [SASS/SCSS with Django](https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-easily-use-sass-scss-with-django/).

I've used the package a few times and have been happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **DIY** out of the box solution

1. Install [Libsass](https://pypi.org/project/libsass/) and [Watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/)

   ```
   pip install libsass watchdog
   ```
2. Create an app named **core**

   ```
   python manage.py startapp core
   ```

#### core/sass.py

```
import os
import time
import site
import sass
import threading
from pathlib import Path
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileClosedEvent


def compiler():
    packageFolders = [
        site.getusersitepackages(),
        *[path for path in site.getsitepackages()],
    ]

    staticFolders = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS.copy()
    staticFolders += [
        os.path.join(app.path, "static") for app in apps.get_app_configs()
    ]

    compileFolders = staticFolders.copy()
    for staticFolder in staticFolders:
        for packageFolder in packageFolders:
            if Path(staticFolder).is_relative_to(packageFolder):
                if staticFolder in compileFolders:
                    compileFolders.remove(staticFolder)

    if settings.DEBUG:

        def watcher(path):
            class Event(FileClosedEvent):
                def dispatch(self, event):
                    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(event.src_path)
                    if extension == ".scss":
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        for d in compileFolders:
                            if os.path.isdir(d):
                                try:
                                    sass.compile(
                                        dirname=(d, d),
                                        output_style="expanded",
                                        include_paths=staticFolders,
                                    )
                                except sass.CompileError as error:
                                    print(error)

            event_handler = Event(path)
            observer = Observer()
            observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
            observer.start()
            try:
                while True:
                    time.sleep(1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                observer.stop()
            observer.join()

        for d in compileFolders:
            if os.path.isdir(d):
                try:
                    sass.compile(
                        dirname=(d, d),
                        output_style="expanded",
                        include_paths=staticFolders,
                    )
                except sass.CompileError as error:
                    print(error)
                thread = threading.Thread(target=watcher, args=(d,), daemon=True)
                thread.start()
    else:
        d = settings.STATIC_ROOT
        if os.path.exists(d):
            try:
                sass.compile(
                    dirname=(d, d),
                    output_style="expanded",
                    include_paths=staticFolders,
                )
            except sass.CompileError as error:
                print(error)
```

#### core/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from core.sass import compiler


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'core'

    def ready(self):
        compiler()
```

For more info, [djboilerplate](https://github.com/devmahdi404/djboilerplate) is a boilerplate project where I have added this out of the **sass** feature