# How to use SASS in Django?

Tags: django, sass

How to make work in django `index.html` with following line?

```
<link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also I can't find much on how to use sass in Django.

I have `index.html` and SASS files from laravel, can I make it work in Django?

Cheers.

Comment: This may help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042664/integrate-sass-scss-with-django)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use `django-webpack-loader` & configure webpack.
This might help https://github.com/khadegd/django-webpack-starter.

**Notice:** I'm the owner of `django-webpack-loader`

Answer (score 4):

Work with `sass` or `less` is not like Laravel. You can use many libraries to do that

1. [django-sass-processor](https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor)
2. [django-libsass](https://github.com/torchbox/django-libsass)